# Left join to return right table's data to only one row in left table

Tags: database, google-bigquery

I'm not sure if this is possible, doing a left join to a right table but inserting it only to a single row in `Table 1` if it finds duplicate `id2`. Please see the table below, I think the illustration explain itself.

Our data warehouse uses Big Query if that helps with anything.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I already found a solution though I'm not sure if this is dirty or there are better ways to this, please feel free to post your answers.

```
select 
   t1.id1,
   t1.id2,
   t1.text,
   ft.number
from Table1 t1
    left join (
        select 
            tt1.id2,
            tt1.text,
            t2.number,
            max(tt1.id1) as id1,
        from Table1 tt1
        left join Table2 t2
            t2.text = tt1.text
        group by 1,2,3
    ) ft
    on ft.id1 = t1.id1
    and ft.id2 = t1.id2
```